# How do I unpack a SQL Server DATETIME in a pyodbc Output Converter function?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am adding output converters to `pyodbc` connection objects to handle date types returned from SQL Server. I was able to unpack a `datetime.time` struct with:

```
tuple   = struct.unpack("HHHI", dateObj)
```

which works well. I cannot figure out the secret sauce for the `datetime.datetime` object, though, which according to the pyodbc docs is a TIMESTAMP_STRUCT, defined [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ODBC-Specification/blob/master/Windows/inc/sqltypes.h):

```
typedef struct tagTIMESTAMP_STRUCT
{
        SQLSMALLINT    year;
        SQLUSMALLINT   month;
        SQLUSMALLINT   day;
        SQLUSMALLINT   hour;
        SQLUSMALLINT   minute;
        SQLUSMALLINT   second;
        SQLUINTEGER    fraction;
} TIMESTAMP_STRUCT;
```

A datum from that column in the db is `2018-01-11 11:50:16.000`, and without the `add_output_convert` trap pyodbc returns:

`TypeError: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 11, 50, 16) is not JSON serializable`

Looks like pyodbc silently drops the fraction, which is fine. Shouldn't the `unpack()` format be one of:

```
tuple = struct.unpack("hHHHHHI", dateObj)  # with missing fraction
tuple = struct.unpack("hHHHHH", dateObj)
```

? The latter simply returns:

`error: unpack requires a string argument of length 12`

For the record, according to `sys.getsizeof` dateObj is 41 bytes. Any suggestions for the format? This is Windows 10 64-bit, as well as Linux 64-bit.

Comment: This is not a sql-server related question. Please use tags properly

Comment: @FLICKER - It *is* about SQL Server. It's about unpacking the raw bytes that SQL Server returns for a given column type.

Comment: @GordThompson, do you need any sql-server knowledge to answer this question? if not, it means sql-server tag is not relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have been chasing down some false leads. The SQL Server ODBC driver does not return 41 bytes of data for a DATETIME value, it only returns 8 bytes. (`sys.getsizeof` returns a value of 41 because it includes "overhead" related to garbage collection.) And there's no way that those 8 bytes represent a TIMESTAMP_STRUCT, so it must be something else.

Starting with a basic test ...

```python
import pyodbc


def datetime_as_string(raw_bytes):
    return raw_bytes


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLmyDb;', autocommit=True)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, datetime_as_string)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

test_value = '2018-01-11 11:50:16'
rtn = crsr.execute("SELECT CAST(? AS DATETIME)", test_value).fetchval()
print(repr(rtn))

crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

... I saw that your test value is represented by `'e\xa8\x00\x00\xa0\x14\xc3\x00'`. A bit of time with the hex converter in Windows Calculator showed me that the contents were not immediately obvious. Playing a hunch, I tried `test_value = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'` and that returned `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` so at least I had a place to start (the "epoch" for SQL Server DATETIME values).

`test_value = '1901-01-01 00:00:00'` (1 year after the epoch) returned `'m\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`, `'m'` is `0x6d`, and `0x016d` is 365, so that was encouraging.

`test_value = '1900-01-01 00:00:01'` (1 second after the epoch) returned `'\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x01\x00\x00'`, `','` is `0x2c`, and `0x012c` is 300.

`test_value = '1900-01-01 00:00:02'` (2 seconds after the epoch) returned `'\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x02\x00\x00'`, `'X'` is `0x58`, and `0x0258` is 600.

So the SQL Server ODBC driver is returning two 4-byte signed integers, the first being the offset from the epoch in whole days, and the second being the partial day in increments of 1/300 seconds.

Therefore I changed my Output Converter function to

```python
def datetime_as_string(raw_bytes):
    tup = struct.unpack("<2l", raw_bytes)
    days_since_1900 = tup[0]
    partial_day = round(tup[1] / 300.0, 3)
    date_time = datetime(1900, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=days_since_1900) + timedelta(seconds=partial_day)
    return date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:23]
```

and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Wow. I spent the whole day yesterday trying to find documentation on the return value _anywhere_ from Microsoft, without luck. I pulled apart the struct and did the math, I should have started with the return value. Thanks!

This seems like a computationally expensive way to return a date value from a database. Why, I wonder. I am assuming both the MS ODBC driver _and_ pyodbc are passing the value through untouched so yes, @FLICKER it is indeed an SQL Server question. Going to link this into the github pyodbc issue in case anyone finds it via search...

Comment: @Omortis re: *"assuming ... pyodbc [is] passing the value through untouched"* - Yes, it is. Wireshark shows that for your original test date/time which the Output Converter function received as `'e\xa8\x00\x00\xa0\x14\xc3\x00'`, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDhju.png) is the packet that SQL Server is sending back over the network.

Comment: Decimal field has the same issue. Any idea how to convert it?

Comment: @GLP did you found any solution regarding Decimal?